# calculate how many variations in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

In this [Link](http://test.addpronetwork.com/flexotech-eCommerce/shop/pressure-gages-coupling/pressure-gage-hose-test-nipples/), I have 4 dropdowns each. First two dropdowns (*Fitting-1 and Fitting-2*) have 5 values and remaining two dropdowns (*meter and centimeter*) have 4 values..

Now, we have to show all options. I don't know how many variations will come?

Please suggest me how to calculate variations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your link Fitting 1 only has 3 choices, but regardless, the math is always the same, you multiply the number of outcomes for each attribute by each other.

```
Variations = n attribute 1 x n attribute 2 x n attribute 3 x n attribute 4
```

Where **n** is the number of possible outcomes. If the first two attributes have 5 possible outcomes each and the second two attributes have 4 outcomes each then your total is

```
Variations = 5 x 5 x 4 x 4 = 400
```